Is there a way to extent the viewport of the visibility detector plugin?
I am wondering on how to extent the viewport or the visibilty area from this plugin flutter visibility detector. I've already looked at the source code, but I'm really new to both dart and flutter, so I'm struggling here.
The reason why I want to extent the visible area is to improve user experience, and with the current viewport/ visible area, it's harming the user experience.
I've already played with the source code and try to increase the sizes of the bound, but seems to not giving me any good result. So I expected for the bounding box/visible area/viewport to be increased so that a widget that even not fully visible could be treated as a partially visible one.
Any feedback is appreciated! Thank you!
